# How do you make a Discord Bot public?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.py

I just made my first discord bot and I was wondering how to make the bot public but couldn't find a way how. Any idea how to make my bot public? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't meet SO guidelines.. This question isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot is public when you create it. Now you just have to make it and host it.

But if you want to verify if your bot is public, you have to go on the website of Discord, in you bot app and in the bot section, you will have a "Public bot" button.